# Can't get MySQL SELECT to work in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to do a basic SELECT like this:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;

  var sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = username";

  db.query(sql, function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var hash = rows.password;
    console.log(hash);
  });

  res.redirect('/');

});
```

Unfortunately, console.log is logging undefined, therefore, I assume that my query is not working. Any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: you never pass your variable to the query, that's why it's not working !

Comment: Have you tried logging `rows`? There's a good chance it's an array.

Comment: mJehanno, can you elaborate?